# How to display an error message when validating a form for all required fields?

Tags: jquery, html

How to display an error message when validating a form for all required fields? I currently have one in place for "noSpace" but i need a more refined approach for all the other error messages.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

jQuery.validator.addMethod("noSpace", function(value, element) { 
return value.indexOf(" ") < 0 && value != ""; 
}, "No space please and don't leave it empty");


$("form").validate({
rules: {
  firstname: {
      required: true,
      alphanumeric: true,
      noSpace: true
  },
  lastname: {
      required: true,
      alphanumeric: true,
      noSpace: true
  },
  phoneNumber: {
      phoneUS: true
  },
  email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
  },
  comment: {
      required: true,
      maxlength: 120,
      alphanumeric: true
  },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        alert('valid form');
        return false;
    }
});

});
```

HTML

```
<form id="form">  
 <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name"/><br/>
 <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name"/><br/> 
 <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" placeholder="Phone Number"/><br/>
 <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"/><br/> 
 <input type="text" name="comment" placeholder="Comment"/>
 <input type="submit" />
</form>
```